# Configure TypeORM in NestJS to use Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, nestjs, typeorm

I've been working with a local mysql configuration but when I try and switch out to an Azure SQL connection I get the error message - ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)

I've created another app which uses tedious and node to make sure it's not something related to Azure.

Below is my config setup -

```js
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

import { UserEntity } from '../user/user.entity';

export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  entities: [UserEntity],
  extra: {
    encrypt: true,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> "ECONNRESET" indicates that the opposite side of the TCP discussion
> abruptly terminated the connection. This is most likely the result of
> one or more application protocol failures. You might check the API
> server logs to see if anything is being reported.

The error (not a warning) indicates that the connection was reset by the peer. The remote peer forced the termination of an existing connection. A forced closure is abrupt because it is unexpected.

Your internet connection may be preventing you from connecting to some servers.

Determine whether anything is interfering with your network (-settings), such as VMs, firewalls, and so on.