# Azure synapse connection with typeORM from nestjs api

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, azure, nestjs

I am testing nestjs but i have doubts about how to create a connection to azure synapse to get data from a table, is this possible? i understand that synapse would be mysql type, i am using this orm config but i get this error.

If there is a better way to do this I would appreciate to be told, thank you very much.

```
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "host",
  "username": "username",
  "password": "password",
  "database": "database",
  "port": 1433,
  "synchronize": true,
  "entities": ["src/modules/**/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  "migrations": ["src/database/migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],
  "seeds": ["./src/database/seeds/*{.ts,.js}"],
  "factories": ["./src/database/factories/*{.ts,.js}"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "src/database/migrations"
  },
  "extra": {
    "encrypt": true
  }

}
```

```
[Nest] 78444   - 09/03/2022 23:11:31   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)... +9342ms
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
```

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69189856/configure-typeorm-in-nestjs-to-use-azure-sql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/how-do-i-debug-error-econnreset-in-node-js